# WinAppDriver - Get Window Handles Titles

Tags: c#, winappdriver, appium-desktop

I need to create an algorithm that switches from one windows to another using WinAppDriver like this `windowsDriver.SwitchTo().Window(allWindowHandles[0])`. However, I also need the Title of the pages found in `windowsDriver.WindowHandles`, or at least the Title of the currently focused page and its hex value. Is there any way I could achieve this using Winappdriver?

I should mention that I'm using WinAppDriver with a Selenium Grid via Appium, for Test Automation purposes. Therefore, I do not know which machine in the grid is going to execute a particular Test.

Comment: Look at www.pinvoke.net.  There are windows dlls that can get properties from the handle of the window.